# CPU fans are not moving, but the PSU works

Tags: memory, motherboard, power-supply, asus, corsair

It's been five days,

**First day**: I turn on my PC, the monitor powers up and doesn't show any signal. I checked the cabinet, and the fans aren't moving at all. I thought it might be the power switch, so I tried jump-starting in the motherboard, but nothing works. I replugged everything, including all the PSU cables, CMOS battery, RAM, HDD, and SSD. And it starts working.

**Second day**: I turn on my PC, and the same problem occurs. I replugged everything (not the CMOS battery this time) and it works.

**Third day**: The same problem. I replugged everything, and this time it didn't work. I left it open (the case open, cables not connected). After an hour tried again, and it works now.

**Fourth day**: The same problem. Replugging didn't work. I left it open for an hour and tried again. It works now.

**Fifth day**: As the problem happens in the morning after I wake up (in-between 7 to 9), I tried waking up early and see whether it’s happening or not. It works just fine; it’s 5 AM and I went back to sleep. I woke up at 8, and the problem is back (fans are not moving). I tested the power supply with the Corsair testing video [here](https://youtu.be/5FWXgQSokF4), and the PSU works just fine. I searched for related problems and posted this problem on [Reddit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reddit). Some claims it is a grounding issue, but I am not sure. And it generally fixes itself when I left the case open.

What is the faulty component here? Or is it a grounding issue? Using my PC for two years, I never encountered this problem.

**My PC specifications:**

CPU: AMD Ryzen 3 2200G 
Motherboard: Asus [EX-A320M](https://www.asus.com/motherboards-components/motherboards/expedition/ex-a320m-gaming/) gaming motherboard

RAM: 2 x 4 GB 3000 MHz HyperX Savage 
Storage: 1 SSD and 2 HDD

PSU: Corsair CX450 (450 watt)

Comment: In spite of the corsair testing, I think it can still be a PSU problem.

Comment: Does your PC have a graphics card?

Comment: nope, no graphics card ༎ຶ‿༎ຶ